# How to get iOS font size and set it to all labels of the app?

Tags: ios, swift, accessibility, whatsapp, dynamic-type-feature

I want to make an app, where font size increase or decrease according to font size maintained in iOS in Settings. If you change font size of your iOS from settings, whatsapp font size displayed accordingly, I want same functionality.

Comment: Can use notification to let all controllers through out the app when Font changes then loop through super view and change font as per the size you set in settings. Also you need to write same code in viewDidiAppear, so that if any screen not loaded can also set the required font size. Hope it make sense.

Answer (score 2):

The iOS functionality you're looking for is the **`Dynamic Type`** that only works for text with implemented [text styles](http://a11y-guidelines.orange.com/mobile_EN/dev-ios-wwdc-17245.html#TextStyles).

Basically, you must :

- Use the `text styles` but beware, their availability depends on your iOS version.[image]
- Tick the `adjustsFontForContentSizeCategory` property *(since iOS 10)* in your interface builder or implement it in code so as to tell the system to handle automatically the Dynamic Type for the object it belongs to *(text styles must be used of course)*.
- Adapt all your constraints to the different sizes your app may encounter.

You can also follow the notifications related to the `Dynamic Type`events as indicated below :[image]
Everything is well explained in this [WWDC video detailed summary](http://a11y-guidelines.orange.com/mobile_EN/dev-ios-wwdc-17245.html) where all the contents and their video timelapses are indicated to reach rapidly the information.

There's also the possibility of [adapting the graphical elements size](http://a11y-guidelines.orange.com/mobile_EN/dev-ios.html#graphical-elements-size) as well with a Dynamic Type implementation.

Answer (score 1):

All you have to do if to use Dynamic Type for your labels. This means not to set it explicitly but to use styles like `Header 1` or `caption`. This styles are depends on user setting in Accessibility and will change automatically. https://www.raywenderlich.com/77092/text-kit-tutorial-swift

Comment: Can you please elaborate you answer in details?

Comment: what kind of details? Select you label/button, set font style to, for example, `Body` or `Footnote`. Thats all you need to do, thanks to Text Kit and Apple

Answer (score 1):

You can use system default sizes for Texts, like,

```
self.label.font = [UIFont preferredFontForTextStyle:UIFontTextStyleHeadline];
```

Please find documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/CustomTextProcessing/CustomTextProcessing.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009542-CH4-SW65).

For other components you can use like [labelFontSize()](https://developer.apple.com/reference/appkit/nsfont/1534629-labelfontsize) and many more,

```
+ (CGFloat)labelFontSize;//Returns the standard font size used for labels.
+ (CGFloat)buttonFontSize;//Returns the standard font size used for buttons.
+ (CGFloat)smallSystemFontSize;//Returns the size of the standard small system font.
+ (CGFloat)systemFontSize;//Returns the size of the standard system font.
```